IntelliSense not working in Visual Studio
I released a game in march and it was the last time I used Unity (and Visual Studio) for a few months. I opened it up today to do some more work, only to discover IntelliSense has stopped working.
Some details:

I'm using C#
Using VS 2022 Community Version 17.2.5, 64-bit


I did recently download VSCode and I think this was before I noticed an issue with Visual Studio, I wouldn't rule out the possibility that the install changed some shared settings and screwed up IntelliSense.
Both Unity and non-Unity dependencies are white in color (using dark theme) and do nothing when Ctrl + clicked. So anything from MonoBehaviour to a List<T> to a class defined in a separate file fail to show up. Ctrl + click still works for things defined in that file; if I define a function and call it somewhere else in the same class, I can flip between those two instances.
What I tried:

checking/unchecking "Auto list members" and "Parameter information" in Visual Studio.

restarting Visual Studio and my machine.

regenerating .csproj files in Unity (which I didn't expect to work since there are non-Unity dependencies having issues too.)


Any suggestions?
Restarted Visual Studio and machine, checking/unchecking "Auto list members" and "parameter information," regenerating .csproj files in Unity. In all cases I would hope IntelliSense would work again and recognize keywords like System or Collections.

seems more like a package problem, maybe vs code uses the same file as visual studio. try to repair your visual studio instalation

Make sure your Visual Studio Editor package is up to date. Window->Package Manager->Visual Studio Editor.  Current version as of writing is 2.0.22

Hello @Kdroscrapshack, please check the following suggestions to troubleshoot the  IntelliSense issue to if the issue persists. If these don't help , please  follow this guide.

There can be many reasons why IntelliSense is failing to work properly on your device. To troubleshoot this issue, please check the followings to see if these help you.
1.Please firstly check if IntelliSense is properly set up, open any script from the Unity Editor. Try declaring a Unity variable, like a GameObject to see if Visual Studio have an auto-complete suggestion for you before you finish typing.(Assembly-Csharp.)
2.Setting Unity’s External Script Editor and try to select another Visual studio instance if you have.

3.Check if the Assembly-Csharp solution is loaded. Right-click on Assembly-Csharp (unloaded) and select Reload project.

4.Please check if you have installed Game development with Unity workload in VS Installer.
5.Check your .NET API compatibility level. Navigate to "Edit > Project Settings" and scroll down to the Other Settings sub-tab, and find the Api Compatibility Level. Try to set the Api Compatibility Level to a different option, and see which is the one that works for your device.
6.Remove all .sln and .csproj files in your Unity project folder. Open Assets > Open C# Project to open Visual Studio.
7.Make sure Visual Studio Editor package and Visual Studio  is up to date.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/gamedev/unity/get-started/getting-started-with-visual-studio-tools-for-unity?pivots=windows#install-or-update-the-visual-studio-editor-package
If the issue persists, please follow this guide to troubleshoot issues with IntelliSense.
Hope it can help you.
